# Android: Saving persistent data

Tags: android, resources, persistent-storage

I have another question also, one I haven't yet got round to having a bash at coding yet so feel free to complain and tell me to try it first. But I just wanted to know if there is a way of storing data such as references to images

i.e I would have a customer object with a name, age etc and then an image which is contained within the drawable class. So when starting up the Activity (after the first time) I could obtain the name/age primitive types easy enough off of the data store but then when it comes to the image if I store it's id how would I then use that as a reference for the bitmap loader. To obviously avoid retaining two images (the one supplied with the app and if I had to store one to keep the association with the customer object).

Comment: I have no idea what earlier question, if any, you are referring to. Don't assume SO users patiently trawl through your questions...

Comment: Woah calm down, I don't assume you do, I was just trying to be friendly and in case anyone did see my previous message. Next time I'll be abrupt and keep to the point, sorry for offending you so badly.

Comment: Whoa, relax, and next time read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the users of your app has a common and amazingly static set of customers you probably don't want to distribute customer images bundled as resources in your app! Store them in the database as [blobs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html).

Comment: It's for a game though and I don't feel sql databases are ideal for games, they arent actually customers that was just an example, but the objects will be generated once then some will be static and some wont.